# Vectorized version of array calculation

Tags: python-2.7, multidimensional-array, vectorization

Is there a way of vectorizing the following array calculation (i.e. without using for loops):

```
for i in range(numCells):
    z[i] = ((i_mask == i)*s_image).sum()/pixel_counts[i]
```

s_image is an image stored as a 2-dimensional ndarray (I removed the colour dimension here for simplicity). i_mask is also a 2-dimensional array of the same size as s_image but it contains integers which are indexes to a list of 'cells' of length numCells.  The result, z, is a 1-dimensional array of length numCells.  The purpose of the calculation is to sum all the pixel values where the mask contains the same index and put the results in the z vector.  (pixel_counts is also a 1-dimensional array of length numCells).

Comment: Perhaps if I created an array or dataframe with a row for every pixel containing the cell index value and the colour setting.  Then sum all the rows with the same index (like a pivot table).  Would this be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one vectorized approach, you can take advantage of [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)  and `matrix-multiplication`, like so -

```
# Generate a binary array of matches for all elements in i_mask against 
# an array of indices going from 0 to numCells 
matches = i_mask.ravel() == np.arange(numCells)[:,None]

# Do elementwise multiplication against s_image and sum those up for 
# each such index going from 0 to numCells. This is essentially doing 
# matix multiplicatio. Finally elementwise divide by pixel_counts 
out = matches.dot(s_image.ravel())/pixel_counts
```

Alternatively, as another vectorized approach, you can do those multiplication and summation with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) as well, which might give a boost to the performance, like so -

```
out = np.einsum('ij,j->i',matches,s_image.ravel())/pixel_counts
```

Runtime tests -

Function definitions:

```
def vectorized_app1(s_image,i_mask,pixel_counts):
    matches = i_mask.ravel() == np.arange(numCells)[:,None]
    return matches.dot(s_image.ravel())/pixel_counts

def vectorized_app2(s_image,i_mask,pixel_counts):
    matches = i_mask.ravel() == np.arange(numCells)[:,None]
    return np.einsum('ij,j->i',matches,s_image.ravel())/pixel_counts

def org_app(s_image,i_mask,pixel_counts):
    z = np.zeros(numCells)
    for i in range(numCells):
        z[i] = ((i_mask == i)*s_image).sum()/pixel_counts[i]
    return z
```

Timings:

```
In [7]: # Inputs
   ...: numCells = 100
   ...: m,n = 100,100
   ...: pixel_counts = np.random.rand(numCells)
   ...: s_image = np.random.rand(m,n)
   ...: i_mask = np.random.randint(0,numCells,(m,n))
   ...: 

In [8]: %timeit org_app(s_image,i_mask,pixel_counts)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.13 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit vectorized_app1(s_image,i_mask,pixel_counts)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.76 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit vectorized_app2(s_image,i_mask,pixel_counts)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.08 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks so much Divakar!  This is great.  Here are the timings with an actual image and numCells of the dimensions I am using: 
`In [643]: %timeit org_app(s_image, i_mask, pixel_counts)
1 loops, best of 3: 363 ms per loop
In [644]: %timeit vectorized_app1(s_image, i_mask, pixel_counts)
1 loops, best of 3: 222 ms per loop
In [645]: %timeit vectorized_app2(s_image, i_mask, pixel_counts)
1 loops, best of 3: 270 ms per loop`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (with all three colours handled).  Not sure how efficient this is.  Anyone got a better solution?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Unravel the mask matrix into a 1-d array
i = np.ravel(i_mask)

# Unravel the image into 1-d arrays for
# each colour (RGB)
r = np.ravel(s_image[:,:,0])
g = np.ravel(s_image[:,:,1])
b = np.ravel(s_image[:,:,2])

# prepare a dictionary to create the dataframe
data = {'i' : i, 'r' : r, 'g' : g, 'b' : b}

# create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Use pandas pivot table to average the colour
# intensities for each cell index value
pixAvgs = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['r', 'g', 'b'], index='i')
pixAvgs.head()
```

Output:

```
            b           g           r
i                                    
-1  26.719482   68.041868  101.603297
 0  75.432432  170.135135  202.486486
 1  92.162162  184.189189  208.270270
 2  71.179487  171.897436  201.846154
 3  76.026316  178.078947  211.605263
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved this problem a different way and it drastically increased the speed.  Instead of using i_mask as above, a 2-dimensional array of indices into the 1-d array of output intensities, z, I created a different array, mask1593, of dimensions (numCells x 45).  Each row is a list of about 35 to 45 indices into the flattened 256x256 pixel image (0 to 65536).

```
In [10]: mask1593[0]
Out[10]: 
array([14853, 14854, 15107, 15108, 15109, 15110, 15111, 15112, 15363,
       15364, 15365, 15366, 15367, 15368, 15619, 15620, 15621, 15622,
       15623, 15624, 15875, 15876, 15877, 15878, 15879, 15880, 16131,
       16132, 16133, 16134, 16135, 16136, 16388, 16389, 16390, 16391,
       16392,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0], dtype=int32)
```

Then I was able to achieve the same transformation as follows using numpy's advanced indexing:

```
def convert_image(self, image_array):
    """Convert 256 x 256 RGB image array to 1593 RGB led intensities."""
    global mask1593
    shape = image_array.shape
    img_data = image_array.reshape(shape[0]*shape[1], shape[2])
    return np.mean(img_data[mask1593], axis=1)
```

And here is the result!  A 256x256 pixel colour image transformed into an array of 1593 colours for display on this irregular LED display:

[image]

Comment: `In [25]: %timeit dis.convert_image(img256)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.56 ms per loop`